# How TCP zero window can be detected on linux

Tags: linux, tcp, solaris, netstat

On Solaris, I'm just using *netstat -an* and getting data under these headers:

```
   Local Address        Remote Address    Swind Send-Q Rwind Recv-Q    State
```

On RHEL however, the headers for the same command read:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address       State
```

To diagnose TCP zero window problem on Solaris I look into Rwind column, and it equals to zero in this case. Now for RHEL, I don't have Rwind. Is there any respective information for RHEL? I also have ss tool, but I couldn't find this information there either.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `ss -ie`?  I don't have a Linux box in front of me now....

Comment: I tried. First problem: Peer Address is OK but port is always scp-config or ndmp, while I'm expecting a number! Second problem: headers are same, but at the end I have this addition for example `uid:502 ino:286506590 sk:1abc5340ffff8103 bic rto:218 rtt:18.625/0.75 ato:40 cwnd:3 send 1.9Mbps rcv_rtt:8581 rcv_space:28150`. Any idea where's what I'm looking for?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for the `cwnd` field shown by `ss -ien`.  The `-n` prevents fancy port names from appearing instead of numbers, which from your comment it seems you don't want.

You can also use the `ino` field there to know which socket each line refers to, and can cross-reference that elsewhere, such as by grepping for that number in `/proc/net/tcp` (or `udp`).

Comment: cwnd is not as clear here. in netstat I know I have 48K of buffer and I can see how much the receiving window size. This field does not exist for most records as well.

Comment: Oh I think I see better now what you're looking for--is it perhaps the `rcv_space` field in `ss`?  Read here: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/782343

Comment: cwnd refers to the congestion window and is measured in TCP segments.